# Minimum number of points to have a point inside every triangle formed by $n$ points

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry, convex-hulls, triangulation

Place $n$ points in a general position on the plane. Call a set $S$ of any points *stabbing* if every triangle formed by the $n$ chosen points contains at least one point from $S$ in its interior. For each $n$ find the smallest number $N$ such that there always exists a stabbing set of $N$ points.

Clearly if the convex hull is a $b$-gon, any triangulation consists of $2n - b - 2$ triangles and we need at least this many points in any stabbing set. When $b = n$ (the chosen points are vertices of a convex polygon), $2n - b - 2 = n - 2$ points are indeed enough. Overall it looks to me that $2n - b - 2$ points might be sufficient.

Comment: How do you get $n-2$?

Comment: When all the points belong to the convex hull it becomes a well-known problem studied e.g. here: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00454-007-9030-1.pdf

Comment: An example that does not match your conjectured bound: take a regular polygon of $n$ vertices, and add $3$ vertices in the inside of the polygon such that the triangle formed by these vertices does not intersect any peripheral region (as descried in the paper you mentioned.  In this paper, it is shown that all the pebble sets for regular polygons are peripheral, thus this construction will require at least one new pebble.

Comment: I don't see how that's a problem. Since we added three points without changing the convex hull, we can actually place up to 6 more pebbles. I edited the question slightly in case it was misleading what I'm actually claiming.

Comment: You're right, I misread the formula to $b-2$.